# Enable and disable jquery sortable on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I have a button that I toggle on click. This button enables the jquery sortable class on a list in my html called "subtaskTaskList". However, I can get the button to toggle but the sortable enable and disable doesn't seem to respond. See code below.

```
<button id="sortButton" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-adjust"></span></button>

 $("#sortButton").click(function(){
    if($("#sortButton").hasClass("glyphicon-adjust")){
        $("#subtaskTaskList").sortable();
        $("#sortButton .glphyicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-adjust glyphicon-lock");
    }else{
     $("#subtaskTaskList").sortable('disable');
        $("#sortButton .glphyicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-lock glyphicon-adjust");
    }
});
```

This code leaves me with an error in my console saying sortable can't be disabled if it had not be initialized. I have tried variations of this code including:

```
$("#sortButton").click(function(){
    if($("#sortButton .glyphicon").hasClass("glyphicon-adjust")){
        $("#subtaskTaskList").sortable();
        $("#sortButton .glphyicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-adjust glyphicon-lock");
    }else{
     $("#subtaskTaskList").sortable('disable');
        $("#sortButton .glphyicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-lock glyphicon-adjust");
    }
});
```

as well as:

```
$("#sortButton").click(function(){
    if($("#sortButton").find("span").hasClass("glyphicon-adjust")){
        $("#subtaskTaskList").sortable();
        $("#sortButton .glphyicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-adjust glyphicon-lock");
    }else{
     $("#subtaskTaskList").sortable('disable');
        $("#sortButton .glphyicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-lock glyphicon-adjust");
    }
});
```

The latter two piece of code don't even cause for toggling of the glyphicon. Any input would be greatly appreciated. I looked over stack overflow but haven't found any specific questions dealing with this issue.

Comment: Please try to make a fiddle that provide the problem in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an external function for switching the sortable enable-disable

```
$(document).on("click","button#switcher",function(){
    sortDisable();
})

function sortDisable() {
    $( "ul#sortme" ).sortable("disable");
}
```

so with your code:

```
$("#sortButton").click(function(){
        if($("#sortButton").find("span").hasClass("glyphicon-adjust")){
            sortEnable("#subtaskTaskList");
            $("#sortButton .glphyicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-adjust glyphicon-lock");
        }else{
            sortDisable("#subtaskTaskList");
            $("#sortButton .glphyicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-lock glyphicon-adjust");
        }
    });


    function sortEnable( target ) {
        $( target ).sortable("enable");
    }
    function sortDisable( target ) {
        $( target ).sortable("disable");
    }
```

Comment: This worked along with adding an id to the span to make selection easier. My real problem was the hasClass wasn't recognizing the right selector. Thanks!

Comment: I didnt test your code, just tried my idea on my current project :) You're welcome

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can enable/disable `sortable()`:

```
$('#sortButton').click(function() {
    //check if sortable() is enabled and change and change state accordingly
  // Getter
  var disabled = $("#subtaskTaskList").sortable( "option", "disabled" );
  if (disabled) {
    $("#subtaskTaskList").sortable( "enable" );
    $("#sortButton .glphyicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-adjust glyphicon-lock");
  }
  else {
    $("#subtaskTaskList").sortable("disable");
    $("#sortButton .glphyicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-lock glyphicon-adjust");
  }
});
```